# Matrix $A$ projects vectors orthogonally to the plane $y=z$. Find $A$.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, 3d, projection-matrices

A $3 \times 3$ matrix $A$ is associated with the transformation that projects vectors in $\mathbb{R}^3$ (orthogonally) onto the above plane $y = z$. Find the matrix A by determining where the vectors $(1,0,0) , (0,1,0)$  and $(0, 0, 1)$ go.

So when projecting the vector $(1,0,0)$ onto the plane, we should probably get $(1,0,0)$ as it is already on the plane. When projecting $(0,1,0)$ and $(0,0,1)$, I am getting $(0,0.5,0.5)$ and $(0,0.5,0.5)$.

Is the matrix $$A = 
    \begin{pmatrix}
    1 & 0 & 0 \\
    0 & 0.5 & 0.5 \\
    0 & 0.5 & 0.5 \\
    \end{pmatrix}
?$$

Comment: Please show your try first.

Comment: If $A$ is a projection, then $A^2=A$. Its kernel should be the orthogonal complement of $y=z$, and it should be the identity map when restricted to that plane. These are all things that you can check for yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the answer is correct.

Projection of $(1,0,0)$ is clearly itself.

To find projection of $(0,1,0)$ onto the plane $y=z$, we minimize $x^2+(y-1)^2+y^2$, and it is $(0,0.5,0.5)$.

Similarly for the other unit basis.

Comment: Thank you for the response. How did you know that you needed to minimize   x^2  +  (y−1)^2  +  y^2 ?

Comment: it's actually $x^2+(y-1)^2+(z-0)^2$ then I replace $z$ with $y$.

Comment: But what do you exactly mean by minimize? Does it relate to finding derivatives of the above equation?

Comment: That is one possible way. then we get $2x=0$ and $2(y-1)+2y=0$. Other more common way to find the basis of the space and project onto the basis. Another way is to find the normal direction to the plane, then subtract the projection onto the normal direction from the original vector.

Comment: Could you please demonstrate using the normal direction to plane method?

Comment: $y=z$ can be written as $y-z=0$ or $\langle (x,y,z), (0,1,-1) \rangle =0$, hence $ (0,1,-1)$ is a normal direction. Let me normalize it as $n=\frac1{\sqrt2}(0,1,-1)$. projection of $e_2=(0,1,0)$ onto the normal direction $(e_2^Tn)n$. Hence projection of $e_2$ onto the plane is $e_2 - (e_2^Tn) n=(0,1,0)-(\frac1{\sqrt{2}})\frac1{\sqrt2}(0,1,-1)=(0,1,0)-(0,0.5,-0.5)=(0,0.5,0.5)$

Answer (score 0):

Vector $\mathrm v := \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 1 & -1\end{bmatrix}^\top$ is **orthogonal** to the plane defined by $y - z = 0$. Thus, the projection matrix that projects onto the *line* spanned by $\rm v$ is

$$\rm P := \dfrac{\,\,v v^\top}{\| v \|_2^2} = \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 0 & 0\\ 0 & \frac{1}{2} & - \frac{1}{2}\\ 0 & - \frac{1}{2} & \frac{1}{2}\end{bmatrix}$$

and the projection matrix that projects onto the orthogonal complement of the aforementioned line, i.e., the given plane itself, is the following

$$\rm I_3 - P = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0\\ 0 & \frac{1}{2} & \frac{1}{2}\\ 0 & \frac{1}{2} & \frac{1}{2}\end{bmatrix}$$